# ¿"se ayudar y aprovechar" en lugar de "ayudarse y aprovecharse"?

Tags: gramática, reflexivos, español-medieval

Estoy leyendo los "Bandos del Alcalde" de Enrique Tierno Galván, *El viejo profesor*. Este buen hombre fue el alcalde de Madrid durante buena parte de la década de los 80, hasta su muerte. Tuvo la idea de ir publicando bandos, es decir proclamas, a sus conciudadanos, que finalmente se publicaron en este libro.

De prosa barroca, formal pero también pícara, me encuentro con expresiones que ya no se escuchan para nada en España.

Hoy me sorprendió esta, que no sé si entiendo bien:

> Sentencia fue y pareceer de aquel grande filósofo Platon que no nació
>   el hombre para sí solo, también fue criado para el uso y utilidad de
>   su patria y amigos. Y todos los que piensan confirman esto, afirmando
>   que los hombres por causa de los mismos hombres fueron formados y
>   engendrados y que **nacieron obligados a se ayudar y aprovechar** los
>   unos a los otros.

¿Es correcto afirmar que la frase que indico en negrita es equivalente a "nacieron obligados a ayudarse y aprovecharse"? Si es así, ¿qué nombre recibe esa separación de la partícula reflexiva, común a dos verbos, para usarla delante?

Comment: Ignoro si el uso separado del pronombre reflexivo tiene una denominación, pero por el contrario, el pronombre que se une al verbo para formar una sola palabra se llama [_pronombre enclítico_](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Pronombre_encl%C3%ADtico)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos lo que nos dice la *Nueva Gramática* (RAE):

> **16.7h** Los infinitivos se construían con pronombres proclíticos hasta el siglo XV, pero sobre todo en el XIII y el XIX:
>
> - Salió el batel a le prender (*Diario Colón*);
> - Los quales príncipes vinieron sin les fazer ninguna fuerça (López Ayala, *Décades*) […]
>
> No se usan en la lengua actual los pronombres proclíticos con los infinitivos, salvo, ocasionalmente y en contextos negativos, en el español popular hablado en Asturias (España), como en *por no lo decir a tiempo*, *para no lo comprar*; etc. […]

Hace referencia a las secciones § 27.1e y § 25.11b (pero no he ido a leérmelas, para decir la verdad)

Creo que es evidente que lo pensado era distribuir la reciprocidad a ambos verbos, porque tiene más sentido *nacieron obligados a ayudarse (recíproco) y aprovecharse (recíproco)*:  Quizás la intención era la idea de *ayudar y aprovechar* como una sola acción conjunta e inseparable (caso en que se permite que un pronombre átono aplique a varios verbos sin tener que repetirse) en vez dos acciones distintas y separables (caso en que se ha de repetir un pronombre átono).

Es decir, si a estos verbos les pusiésemos como verbo principal de una oración, habría una diferencia clara entre las siguientes oraciones:

- Nos ayudamos y aprovechamos
  <sup>(Una acción de ayudar y aprovechar)</sup>
- Nos ayudamos y nos aprovechamos
  <sup>(Dos acciones: una de ayudar, y otra de aprovechar)</sup>

Solo es posible hacer esto con proclisis.  Con enclisis, ya no es:

- Queremos ayudarnos y aprovechar
  <sup>(casi suena bien ya que aprovechar puede ser intransitivo excepto si tomamos una frase análoga...)</sup>
- Quiero prepararlo y comer.
  <sup>(Aquí preparo una cosa, pero no la como, simplemente «como» — quizás la cosa que preparé, quizás no)</sup>

Pero ya que se encuentran en flexión de infinitivo en el ejemplo, no hay buena opción porque en la gramática moderna la única opción es hacer énclisis con ambos verbos y así aludiendo a dos acciones distintas o quizás incluso abriéndose a la interpretación de *ayudarse* (reflexivo) y *aprovecharse* (recíproco).  Entonces, se aprovechó de un sintaxis medieval (pero, creo yo, bastante entendible a los oídos modernos) para que las acciones quedasen interpretadas como una única.

Comment: ¡Fantástica explicación! Me ha recordado las Coplas de Jorge Manrique: _Nuestras vidas son los ríos / que van a dar en la mar, / qu'es el morir; / allí van los señoríos / derechos a **se acabar** / e consumir;_

Answer (score 0):

No.
Quizás la regla en castellano antiguo permitía escribir el reflexivo de esa forma.

Otro ejemplo es: **cayóse** que en realidad viene siendo **se cayó**.

Así como muchos otros más usados en castellano antiguo.

Comment: Antes sí se podía hacer (pero hablamos de siglos y no de décadas). Por cierto, *cayóse* es la grafía pre-2010, ahora es *cayose* por ser palabra llana que termina en vocal.

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta. ¿A qué contestas "No"?

Comment: Que **se** no es intercambiable en este caso.

Comment: @Ale Respondiendo específicamente a la pregunta de si debe considerarse el texto como equivalente a "ayudarse y aprovecharse" (o "sacar provecho unos de otros", más bien), la respuesta es sí: son intercambiables. Que el pronombre reflexivo no se use separado desde hace siglos es otra cuestión.